# How do I prevent DateTime parameter from invoking before DataGridView Columns are filled out?

Tags: datagridview

I have a DataGridView with 4 columns that can be added to or edited dynamically using parameters. Everything works as long as the StartDate (column 4) is filled in first. When I fill the DGV normally (from left to right) the Query fails and gives an ERROR  "System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." How can I prevent the DateTime parameter from firing before the DataGridView row is completed.

I have tried to insert a DBNull into the StartDate column cell until the DGV is filled, but get a Stored Procedure ERROR  'Too Many arguments'. I have included the Stored Procedure code in Comments at the bottom of the code for reference. 
 Thanks in advance, lejoc

Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

```
Private connectionstring As String = "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Employment;Integrated Security=True;"

Private Sub PopulatePositionComboBox()
    Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlDa As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Position", sqlCon)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        sqlDa.Fill(dt)
        cbxPositionID.ValueMember = "PositionID"
        cbxPositionID.DisplayMember = "Position"
        Dim topItem As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        topItem(0) = 0
        topItem(1) = "-Select-"
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(topItem, 0)
        cbxPositionID.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PopulatePositionComboBox()
    PopulateDataGridView()
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
    Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlDa As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Employee", sqlCon)
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        sqlDa.Fill(dt)
        DgvEmployment.DataSource = dt
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub DgvEmployment_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DgvEmployment.CellValueChanged
    If DgvEmployment.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
        Using sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
            sqlCon.Open()
            Dim dgvRow As DataGridViewRow = DgvEmployment.CurrentRow
            Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("AddOrEdit", sqlCon)
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

            ' INSERT
            If dgvRow.Cells("txtEmployeeID").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", 0)
            Else
                ' UPDATE
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Convert.ToInt32(dgvRow.Cells("txtEmployeeID").Value))
            End If

            ' PROBLEM AT HERE, FAILS Query because looking for VALID DATE after 'txtName' is entered 
            'ERROR MESSAGE = System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", If(dgvRow.Cells("txtName").Value Is DBNull.Value, "", dgvRow.Cells("txtName").Value.ToString()))
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PositionID", Convert.ToInt32(If(dgvRow.Cells("cbxPositionID").Value Is DBNull.Value, "0", dgvRow.Cells("cbxPositionID").Value)))
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office", If(dgvRow.Cells("txtOffice").Value Is DBNull.Value, "", dgvRow.Cells("txtOffice").Value.ToString()))
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", Convert.ToDateTime(If(dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value Is DBNull.Value, "0", dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value)))
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            PopulateDataGridView()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub


'The code for the STORED PROCEDURE  dbo.AddOrEdit
'    CREATE PROC AddOrEdit
'@EmployeeID int,
'@Name varchar(100),
'@PositionID int,
'@Office varchar(50),
'@StartDate date
'As
'If  @EmployeeID  = 0
'INSERT INTO Employee (Name, PositionID, Office, StartDate)
'VALUES (@Name, @PositionID, @Office, @StartDate)
'Else
'UPDATE Employee
'    Set
'Name = @Name,
'PositionID = @PositionID,
'Office = @Office,
'StartDate = @StartDate
'WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
```

I expect the DGV to be filled in from left to right with the 'StartDate' as the last column. EG Name, PositionID, Office, StartDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing your `StartDate` column is nullable, then I thinkg it can be resolved by changing line

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate",  Convert.ToDateTime(If(dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value Is DBNull.Value, "0", dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value)))
```

to

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", If(dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value Is DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value)))
```

So if it's not filled, save `NULL` to database, otherwise convert your `txtStartDate` field to `DateTime` and save that.

Saving "0" as DateTime won't work.

Comment: Hi @Oak. Well done, Your answer worked with a little refinement. The corrected code is:  sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", If(dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value Is DBNull.Value, DBNull.Value, Convert.ToDateTime(dgvRow.Cells("txtStartDate").Value)))  Thanks heaps.

Comment: Oh, I see I left there extra "if(" when reshuffling the code… Sorry for that :-)